TYPO3 - Pass arguments of searchForm to 2 Plugins
I'am migrating a an old flexform to multiple plugins in TYPO3 12.
Now it seems I have a simple problem but could not find a good solution.
I have 2 plugins:

searchForm

List


both are using the same Controller and have 2 different Actions:

searchFormAction
ListAction

Now I need to have a simple selectbox in the searchform and I need the arguments of the searchForm in both plugins and also in both actions not only in one.
It seems, that when I create an selectbox in searchform via
<f:form.select name="myproperty" options="{0: 'Please Select', 1: 'first option'}" value="{selectedValueFromController}"/>

it results in HTML
<select name="tx_myextension_searchform[myproperty]" ....>

so it puts "searchform" in the selectname.
I assume, this is why I can only get its post-values in controller-action "searchFormAction" and not in listAction.
I do this via:
$arrRequest = $this->request->getArguments();

how can I get the values of searchform in both actions ?
Thanks for any hints or also workarounds. How can it be done in "best practice"

$this->request->getArguments() only returns values that are prefixed with the plugin name tx_myextension_searchform. But you can still access them via $_POST/$_GET globals.
There are multiple valid solutions to your problem, but it depends on how your project works, if you can find a clean easy solution or have to rebuild your whole extension.

Thanks, basically you are right. I have to access via $_POST or $_GET. I also found a way to get all request-vars from all plugins of one extension. I use:
$ArrAllRequestParams = $this->request->getParsedBody(['tx_myextensionname']);
This should replace old GeneralUtility::_POST() since TYPO3 12.2 according to this link: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/12.2/Deprecation-99633-GeneralUtilityPOST.html

The better solution is to set both plugins to the same namespace.
This is done via typoscript (e.g. in setup.typoscript)
plugin.tx_MYEXTENSION_MYPLUGIN.view.pluginNamespace = MYNAMESPACE

The value of MYNAMESPACE is in your case "tx_myextension_searchform".
After having done that, you can access the values of your search-form via
$this->request->getArguments() 

and all the other functions that are available.
